# How do I determine the slowest component of my shell pipeline?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cut, cat

I have an extremely long and complicated shell pipeline set up to grab 2.2Gb of data and process it.  It currently takes 45 minutes to process.  The pipeline is a number of cut, grep, sort, uniq, grep and awk commands tied together.  I have my suspicion that it's the grep portion that is causing it to take so much time but I have no way of confirming it.

Is there anyway to "profile" the entire pipeline from end to end to determine which component is the slowest and if it is CPU or IO bound so it can be optimised?

I cannot post the entire command here unfortunately as it would require posting proprietary information but I suspect it is the following bit checking it out with htop:

```
grep -v ^[0-9]
```

Comment: Sort has to read its entire input to sort, i would suspect that's a problem. If i had that much data and a complicated pipeline i would rewrite it in Perl instead.

Comment: Sort is after the uniq part of the pipeline and only has to sort about 1500 items so I don't think it is that.

Comment: You do know that uniq expects sorted input?

Comment: It doesn't "require" sorted input (I confirmed this) but is optimal if you do sort it first.  In this case I'm not bothered as the pre-uniq row count is about 15000 which takes less than a second to rip through on this box.  Regarding perl - I'm considering it.

Comment: OK, just to satisfy my curiosity, which implementation of uniq is that? I haven't heard of one that doesn't require sorted input. Anyhow, that grep shouldn't be a problem, so i would guess it's more IO bound

Comment: Coreutils uniq.  I might be incorrect with my initial assumption.  I've found the problem now - it was grep.  Will post my own answer below.

Comment: I found ["The input need not be sorted, but repeated input lines are detected only if they are adjacent."](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/uniq-invocation.html) so i'm worried that you might have duplicate lines that are not repeated. `sort -u` should take care of that though.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I've updated my scripts accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem myself after some further experimentation.  It appears to be due to the encoding support in grep.  Using the following hung the pipeline:

```
grep -v ^[0-9]
```

I replaced it with sed as follows and it finished in under 45 seconds!

```
sed '/^[0-9]/d'
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to gradually build up the pipeline, timing each addition, and taking as much out of the equation as possible (such as outputting to a terminal or file). A very simple example is shown below:

```
pax:~$ time ( cat bigfile >/dev/null )
real 0m4.364s
user 0m0.004s
sys  0m0.300s

pax:~$ time ( cat bigfile | tr 'a' 'b' >/dev/null )
real 0m0.446s
user 0m0.312s
sys  0m0.428s

pax:~$ time ( cat bigfile | tr 'a' 'b' | tail -1000l >/dev/null )
real 0m0.796s
user 0m0.516s
sys  0m0.688s

pax:~$ time ( cat bigfile | tr 'a' 'b' | tail -1000l | sort -u >/dev/null )
real 0m0.892s
user 0m0.556s
sys  0m0.756s
```

If you add up the user and system times above, you'll see that the incremental increases are:

- 0.304 (0.004 + 0.300) seconds for the `cat`;
- 0.436 (0.312 + 0.428 - 0.304) seconds for the `tr`;
- 0.464 (0.516 + 0.688 - 0.436 - 0.304) seconds for the `tail`; and
- 0.108 (0.556 + 0.756 - 0.464 - 0.436 - 0.304) seconds for the `sort`.

This tells me that the main things to look into are the `tail` and the `tr`.

Now obviously, that's for CPU only, and I probably should have done multiple runs at each stage for averaging purposes, but that's the basic first approach I would take.

If it turns out it really is your `grep`, there are a few other options available to you. There are numerous other commands that can strip lines not starting with a digit but you *may* find that a custom-built command for doing this may be faster still, pseudo-code like (untested, but you should get the idea):

```
state = echo
lastchar = newline
while not end of file:
    read big chunk from file
    for every char in chunk:
        if lastchar is newline:
            if state is echo and char is non-digit:
                state = skip
            else if state is skip and and char is digit:
                state = echo
        if state is echo:
            output char
        lastchar = char
```

Custom, targeted code like this can sometimes be made more efficient than a general-purpose regex processing engine, simply because it can be optimised to the specific case. Whether that's true is this case, or *any* case for that matter, is something you should test. My number one optimisation mantra is *measure, don't guess!*

Comment: Thanks - this is a really elegent approach to the analysis.  Much appreciated.  I'll mark this as the answer on the basis that it's the correct way to approach the problem.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward with *zsh*:

```
zsh-4.3.12[sysadmin]% time sleep 3 | sleep 5 | sleep 2
sleep 3  0.01s user 0.03s system 1% cpu 3.182 total
sleep 5  0.01s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 5.105 total
sleep 2  0.00s user 0.05s system 2% cpu 2.121 total
```